# check data in firebase realtime database doesn't work

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm tryng to check if a bandcode already exists but it doesn't work. Exists returns false ever.

This is the code:

```
databaseReference.child("Band_Codes").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            if(data.child(codeCheck).exists()){
                                //do something
                            }
                            else{
                                //do something
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
```

[image]

```
System.out.prinln(data.child(codeCheck)) returns: DataSnapshot { key = kN9VIY6AC3Zx5FP, value = null }
```

kN9VIY6AC3Zx5FP is also present in the DB.

The image is only an example.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing `codeCheck` as key. but it is not the key, it's the value. You should pass `"code"` like `data.child("code")` and check if its value equals to `codeCheck`.